# Htable and .add depracated, what should i use instead?this is in scala

Tags: scala, hbase

I have been using below function to save my data into Hbase, can someone help me how to use updated api or some example? given below is my code:

```
 def getConnection():(Connection, Configuration) ={
    val config = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "node-01.algo,node-02.algo")
    config.set("hbase.master", "node-01.algo:60000")
    config.set("zk.connectiontimeout.ms", "10000")
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientport", "2181")
    config.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure")
    val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config)
    (connection, config)
  }
def addRecord(tableName: String, rowKey: String, family: String, qualifier: String, value: String) ={
    val conTuple = getConnection()
    val connection = conTuple._1
    val table = new HTable(conTuple._2, tableName)
    val theput= new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey))
    theput.add(Bytes.toBytes(family), Bytes.toBytes(qualifier), Bytes.toBytes(value))
    table.put(theput)
    table.close()
    connection.close()
  }
```

Htable has been depracated, and asking me to use Table instead.

Answer (score 0):

Data frames implicitly support only [Hive](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#saving-to-persistent-tables),

There is library for saving to hbase,but you have to do a lot manual work [spark on hbase](https://github.com/cloudera-labs/SparkOnHBase)

Another option is to setup [Apache Phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html)